# In the Slack API, what's the difference between an im, an mpim and a group?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Slack has message events for [`message.group`](https://api.slack.com/events/message.groups), [`message.im`](https://api.slack.com/events/message.im) and [`message.mpim`](https://api.slack.com/events/message.mpim).

As I understand it, `im` means it's a private message to one person, and `mpim` is a private messaging conversation with multiple people. A group is described as a private channel. So what's the difference between an mpim conversation, and a group then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A private channel is meant to be more persistent: it has a name and a topic like public channels and have no limits.

mpim conversations, on the other hand, are limited to 9 participants.

Adding a member to an mpim will create a new conversation, while inviting a member to a private channel can retain its history.